# Favicon in subdirectory all subdomain

Tags: html, favicon, subdirectory

I am used to just save the favicon.ico in the `public_html` folder for adding the favicon.

The problema I have now is that I want to display the in all the files of a certain subdirectory, ( `example.com/example` "onwards" ) just putting it there, doesnt seem to do the job.

I know I could go document by document and add:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

But I hope there is a more practical way, first I thought there might be a way trough CSS but that doesnt seem to be the case.

This would have come in handy because every document already includes:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
```

So any ideas or workarounds to how to solve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will have to specify the favicon using the `link rel=...` notation.

Browsers will search only in the root directory of the domain for a default `/favicon.ico`. Any variations from that you have to specify explicitly.

Comment: Too bad! :( Thanks for the quick answer, so, no way through css right?

Comment: @Trufa nope, favourite icons are not controllable through CSS.

Comment: thats a pitty! :) Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `<link>` element is the right way to go. Use a template engine (e.g. [Template-Toolkit](http://template-toolkit.org/)) to avoid duplicating common content manually.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!! I´ll take a look, could come in really handy (if not for this for other project)!

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the most elegant way, and i came here to find a solution.
Unfortunaly the given answers did not suited for me.

In my case i working on a localhost (via private ip)

this is what i did :

```
        <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo rtrim($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])); ?>favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above don't waste time on searching.  is the only way in that case. When you will be checking out results of your markup changes, remember that browser cache can be tricky.

Answer (score -1):

redirect favicon.ico url for all subdomains to public_html's favicon.ico

ie. subdomain.website.com/favicon.ico should go to www.website.com/favicon.ico