# How do I create a favicon.ico file for every directory I want?

Tags: favicon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Favicon in subdirectory all subdomain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128570/favicon-in-subdirectory-all-subdomain)

My website is one big website, with many little projects in it. Each of the projects also have their own `favicon.ico` file (the one which is shown on the left hand side of the url bar), but even if I put a `favicon.ico` file inside a subdirectory, it will still not show up, and will use the `favicon.ico` file put at the root directory.

How do I solve this problem?

Lucas

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set it on a per-page basis, like this:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://example.com/myicon.ico" />
```

inside the `<head>..</head>` tags.

Setting it on a per directory basis does not work.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks, but I already have > 100 pages, and it will be hard to do.